# При загрузке странице раскрывающийся список должен быть открыт

Tags: javascript, jquery, список, toggle

Здравствуйте. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста, в `js` не силач.

Есть код:

```
$('.spoiler-body').hide();

$('.spoiler-title').click(function(){

    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Необходимо чтобы изначально список был раскрыт.

Comment: `$('.spoiler-title').next().show()`  а вообще проще `display: block`  в `css` поставить

Comment: И получается когда добавляю ваш код в js, то список будет открыт, но закрываться уже не будет, правильно?

Comment: Почему, вы же там делаете `slideToggle`, значит будет то выезжать, то уезжать...... если конечно `$('.spoiler-title').next()` вообще список) а то может у вас там список совсем другие селекторы имеет

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, <script>
  $('.spoiler-title_r').next().show();
  $('.spoiler-body').hide();
$('.spoiler-title').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
  </script> правильная структура скрипта  ? Просто не разъезжается список теперь

Comment: у вас `spoiler-title_r` а должно быть `spoiler-title` если я правильно понял.........html + css в вопорос добавьте

Comment: http://what.hol.es/parikmaher.html на странице слева раскрывающийся список который должен быть открыт при загрузке страницы (spoiler-title_r) , а справа как обычно закрыт (spoiler-title)

Comment: все относящееся к вопросу должно быть в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допилил сам, спасибо за подсказки.

```
$('.spoiler-title_r').next().show();
$('.spoiler-title_r').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
});
$('.spoiler-body').hide();
$('.spoiler-title').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```